# Como configurar RaspBerry Pi para executar apenas uma aplicação em Python?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi, pyqt-5

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em **Python** para executar em um **RaspBerry Pi**, essa aplicação irá iniciar assim que o dispositivo for ligado. Estou usando o **PyQt5** para fazer as telas.

- Como posso configurar o **RaspBerry Pi** para essa finalidade?
- É possível instalar apenas o **Raspbian Stretch Lite** ou tenho que instalar o **Raspbian Stretch with desktop** para que as telas sejam exibidas?

Comment: Recomendo buscar as próximas dúvidas sobre o Raspberry Pi na [comunidade própria](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) e tratar apenas de coisas atinentes à programação aqui.

Comment: Obrigado, não sabia da existência dessa comunidade. Devo remover essa pergunta?

Comment: Acredito que não. É só que lá é só gente que mexe com isso e vão te dar respostas mais completas, rápidas e precisas. Isso se já não estiver no fórum.

Answer (score 2):

> Como posso configurar o RaspBerry Pi para essa finalidade?

Uma forma fácil de fazer essa configuração é colocar um comando para rodar seu arquivo `.py` em `/etc/network/if-up.d/upstart`. Você precisa abrir o arquivo:

`sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart`

E depois procurar a parte `all_interfaces_up()` e adicionar o caminho para seu arquivo:

```
all_interfaces_up() {
python /caminho/para/seu/arquivo.py # adicionar essa linha aqui
# vai ter mais coisa escrita aqui    
}
```

Há [outras formas de rodar uma aplicação](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/) assim que o Python inicia. Você pode escolher uma que melhor te atenda.

> É possível instalar apenas o Raspbian Stretch Lite ou tenho que instalar o Raspbian Stretch with desktop para que as telas sejam exibidas?

É possível somente na versão Lite.

Comment: Não funcionou, vou pesquisar mais e volto a postar aqui.

Comment: Procure solução com `systemd`. Tem no link que recomendei. Quando precisei e tive problemas, eu usei ela e funcionou.

Comment: Adicionei as linhas no /etc/rc.local para executar o meu script python. Ele tenta executar mas da o erro "QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display". O que pode ser?